# Is cross product defined for vectors of more than three variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is cross product defined for vectors of more than three variables

Comment: The answer is NO!

Comment: Please google it.

Comment: Not really, but have a look at this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product and check the subsections "Cross product as an exterior product" and "Multilinear algebra" which indicate how one may look at this in higher dimensions.

Comment: @vishnuvardhanreddykavali Not really.  You can always take the "product" of $n-1$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, but even in $\Bbb R^3$ the result isn't *really* a vector.  The cross product just isn't a very good product.  The exterior (wedge) product does about the same thing as the cross product in $\Bbb R^3$ but has much nicer properties (including working on two vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ for any $n$).  Look into it.

Comment: Yes and no. The cross product really comes from taking the imaginary part of the product of pure imaginary quaternions. This process can be repeated in $\Bbb R^7$ by way of the octonions.

Comment: But in $\Bbb R^7$, there's no accepted standard cross product.  You have to make an arbitrary choice of one of the $480$ possible cross products.

Comment: @Bye_World True that.

Answer (score 1):

The cross product can be written formally as
$$  \mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{y} = \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{e}_1 & \mathbf{e}_2 & \mathbf{e}_3 \\ x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\ y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \end{vmatrix}. $$
There is a unique way to extend this to $n-1$ vectors in $n$ dimensions:
$$ \times(\mathbf{x}^{(1)} , \dotsc, \mathbf{x}^{(n-1)}) = \begin{vmatrix} 
\mathbf{e}_1 & \mathbf{e}_2 &  \cdots & \mathbf{e}_n \\ 
x_1^{(1)} & x_2^{(1)} & \cdots & x_n^{(1)} \\ 
x_1^{(2)} & x_2^{(2)} & \cdots & x_n^{(2)} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_1^{(n-1)} & x_2^{(n-1)} & \cdots & x_n^{(n-1)} \end{vmatrix}; $$
this still has the orthogonality and anti-commutativity of the normal cross product.

There is also a (non-unique) way to define a [seven-dimensional cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product).